# Truncating a pst-3dplot Surface

Tags: xetex, pstricks, graphs, pst-3dplot

The graph of a function and the MWE are given below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3.2,-2.73)(3.18,3.65)
\psplotThreeD[
  plotstyle = line,
  linecolor = blue,
  yPlotpoints = 150,
  xPlotpoints = 150,
  linewidth = 0.5pt,
  hiddenLine = true
](-3,3)(-3,3)
{x 100 mul cos 3 mul y 100 mul sin 3  mul sub}

\pstThreeDCoor[
  xMin = -4,
  xMax = 4,
  yMin = -4,
  yMax = 4,
  zMin = -4,
  zMax = 4,
  arrows = <->,
 IIIDlabels, IIIDticks
]

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like to truncate the graph of the function where the z-values are only on [-3, 3] (so that the graph looks like having plateaus) while still keeping the x and y-values to be on [-3, 3] as well.

How do I do this? I tried using `\parametricplotThreeD` to no avail. I know that I can use `pst-solides3d` but I would like to stick with `pst-3dplot` for consistency with other graphs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{pspicture}(-3.2,-2.73)(3.18,3.65)
\psplotThreeD[plotstyle = line,linecolor = blue,yPlotpoints = 150,xPlotpoints = 150,
  linewidth = 0.5pt,hiddenLine = true,](-3,3)(-3,3)
    {x 100 mul cos 3 mul y 100 mul sin 3  mul sub 
      dup 3 gt { pop 3 } if 
      dup -3 lt {pop -3 } if}
\pstThreeDCoor[
    xMin = -4,xMax = 4,yMin = -4,yMax = 4,zMin = -4,zMax = 4,
    arrows = <->,IIIDlabels, IIIDticks,]        
\end{pspicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes like that ^^

Comment: May I know how you did it? ^^

Comment: See edited answer ...

Comment: Thank you. Suppose I use `algebraic` in the parameter, how does the code change? ^^

Comment: No, with the algebraic mode the macro itself has to be modified

Comment: I see. Equation of the surface should be done with PSTricks code then.

Another question: Is it possible to put holes on the "plateaus"? Like the cut portions have no covers?